# No rational points on $x^n+a=y^2$ for all $n>4$"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, hyperelliptic-curves

Is there rational (or better integer) $a$ such that for all $n>4$,$x^n+a=y^2$
has no rational points?

Comment: Confusion warning: The question is about **rational** solutions.

Comment: According to M. Stoll's ratpoints program, a=6 seems to work, but I don't know if it is easy to prove.